# Java: Reasoning behind mandatory (implicit) declaration of Object's method in any interface definition

Tags: java, interface

In the JLS in paragraph 9.2 it says

> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by the interface.

If a declaration were hypothetically left out, a compile-time error would result. But why does the compiler demand these declarations, when any class inherits Object's methods anyway, i.e. regarding these methods a certain behaviour is already guaranteed? What is the reasoning behind requiring these declarations in any interface definition?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255073/why-do-interfaces-extend-object-according-to-the-class-file-format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
public void printList(List<?> list) {
   System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

For this to work the type `List` must declare the method `toString()`. Keep in mind that `List` is not a subtype of `Object`.

Comment: Check the JSL http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2, it says the interface will have Object as direct supertype if it does have direct superinterfaces