# Do interface references require a cast to be assigned to a class Object reference?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, casting, reference

While revising for the Java SE 8 Programmer I (formerly OCA) Certification exam, I came across the following statement:

> "A reference to an interface requires an explicit cast to be assigned
>   to a reference of any class, even one that implements the interface.
>   An interface reference requires an explicit cast to be assigned to a
>   class reference."

I think this is slightly inaccurate as it is possible to assign a reference to an interface to a reference of the class Object without an explicit cast.

```
interface Animal {}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Dog();
        Dog dog = animal; // Doesn't compile - requires explicit cast to Dog
        Object o = animal; // Compiles
    }
}
```

Is this due to a link between the Object class and interfaces akin to that described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16255298/9472445) relating to the class file format?
From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19469368/9472445) relating to accessing the Java Object class methods using an interface reference, I've summarized that:

- Using an interface reference, you can only access methods defined in
  the interface but not class specific methods.
- Interfaces have "Hidden Declared" methods of class Object.
- You can access methods of the Object class via any interface reference because, although an interface 
  doesn't extend from the Object class, every root interface in Java has implicit declarations of 
  methods corresponding to each method in the Object class.

> [**JLS §9.2 - Interface members**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2):
>
> If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface
>   implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature
>   s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public
>   instance method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t
>   declared in Object, unless a method with the same signature, same
>   return type, and a compatible throws clause is explicitly declared by
>   the interface.

Comment: Looks like the author of the statement might have forgotten about the `Object` type.

Comment: `Is this due to a link between the Object class` - Yes.

Comment: Hey! First, thank you for taking your time writing and formatting a question. Second, I think you've already answered it yourself. Anyways for clarity, interfaces are nothing but templates for classes and as all classes inherit from ```Object``` the given code works as it does.